# Is there a way to make dask read_csv ignore empty files?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, dask

I have a dasaset with 200k files per day, those files are rather small `.txt.gz` where 99% are smaller that 60kbytes. Some of this files are empty files of size 20 because of gzip compression.

When I try to load the the whole directory with dask I get a `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError`. Since I plan to load this directly from S3 each day I wonder if I can ignore or skip those files via `dd.read_csv()`. I haven't found any option to control the error handling in the  documentation for dask's [`read_csv()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv) and pandas's  [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Of course, **I can copy all the files from s3 to the local hard disk and scan and remove all offending files prior to loading in Dask** but that is going to be slower (copying all the 200k files).

In principle I just want to load all this 200k CSV files into Dask to convert them to fewer parquet files. So I'm not even sure if Dask is the best tool for this, but if there an easy way to make it work I wo

Comment: Why would you need pandas/dask for what could be done with OS tools?

Comment: I think that is already in the OP , I don't want to copy 200k files from S3 to local disk, as doing that (in parallel) is non-trivial. It will also be slower as I said,  but also I'm not fond of the the added complexity of another tool to copy files and scripting to remove this particular type of error if it's possible to do with Dask directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to do this is through exceptions:

```
import pandas.io.common

for i in range(0,len(file_paths)):
   try:
      pd.read_csv(file_paths[i])
   except pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError:
      print file_paths[i], " is empty"
```